# How to control user input with CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

I am really not an expert in iOS but I have been working on an app to learn things through. In the app I have a tableView with two rows for input to core data:  an `NSDate` attribute and an `NSString` attribute (numerical value).

The user in the app enters these values **each day.** What I am trying to achieve is to have some kind of input check before storing the values like:

**1-** First, I would like to make sure that the NSString attribute (which is mainly just numbers) the user entered one day is **never less** than the previous day and can never put two values for a same day.

**2-** Then, I would like to have the NSDate attribute to always **start by the current date** and **never allow the user to chose a past date.**

I sincerely apologize if my question is trivial, I really need some help with this.

**UPDATE:** Problem number nsdate input constraint is solved.Now the following issue still persists:

- I want to allow the user to input values in their respective cell in the tableview. Then when he clicks on **save button(**it is implemented), an **alert or a simple text message** is shown asking him  to change the value entered because the value he entered is smaller than the previous day. The previous day is defined by the NSDate input attribute he would chose( see screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJnkP.png  , where cell 1 represents the attribute numerical value and cell 2 is the NSdate attribute.

Comment: If your string is only for storing numbers then what you should really be using is `NSNumber` instead of `NSString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this piece of code for  **I would like to have the NSDate attribute to always start by the current date and never allow the user to chose a past date.**

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:0];
 NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[shiftDatePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

Use your `UIDatePicker` name instead of mine.

the answer of your first question is little bit therotical .But i hope you will understand it.

first you should get the object of Table in your `UIViewController`. Fetch the value from `CoreData` and match with the user entered. If user has entered a greater value then no problem. If it is less or equal to previous value Show error to them.

Use this for your first question.

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)getBasicRequestForEntityName: (NSString *)entityName
{
    //Get Fetch request for particuler entity.
    NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext = [[AppDelegate getAppdelegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    return request;
}


-(NSMutableArray*)getAllRequestedShifts
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [self getBasicRequestForEntityName:@"YOUR ENTITY NAME"];

    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"previous value" ascending:NO];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray array];

    if (!error && [results count] > 0)
    {

        for (int k=0; k<[results count]; k++)
        {
            YourentityObject *requestShiftObj = [results objectAtIndex:k];
            [arr addObject:requestShiftObj];
        }

    }
    return arr;
}
```

In your `- (void)viewDidLoad` method use this line

```
NSMutableArray*  arrayOfSentRequest=[self getAllRequestedShifts];
```

This will return you the list of all objects which lies in your `CoreData` with maxvalue object at top.

Retrive this object and use the property **previousvalue** and compare to the value which is being entered and generated result according to algo.

Use this code

```
NSDateFormatter* dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateF setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
  NSString *currentDate=[dateF stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate  * currentDateObj=[dateF dateFromString:currentDate];
    NSDate  * shiftDateFieldObj=[dateF dateobjectfromDB];
NSTimeInterval timeDifferenceBetweenDates = [shiftDateFieldObj timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDateObj];
 if (timeDifferenceBetweenDates>0.0)
  {
      Enter the value to text field ;
  }
  else
  {
       show alert
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the date to always start with current works(what if we just want the current date of when the user access the app without allowing him to modify the date?)......Oh and for the algorithm u explained, can you please provide some sample code for how do you match a value before storing, that would be very helpful

Comment: yeah put this code in View did load when view will be loaded on that time date picker will show current date

Comment: okey so i understood how to edit the pickerview as u explained very well. now i am still a little bit stuck with the value always bigger than previous one issue... i ll edit and update the whole post for more visibility

Comment: the process above is self explanatory

Comment: Sorry to ask, but where should the new code u added be called?

Comment: where you want to check whether previous value is greater or not?

Comment: I set the answer for the second issue as valid answer for the question. I ll post the question about the first issue in a different question, with more code in detail :).

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to up vote :), can you check my new question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742725/ios-how-to-use-predicates-nsexpression-to-check-user-input-for-validity-and-con