# iOS: How to use predicates NSexpression to check user input for validity and conformance

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my app using coredata i have an entity with two attributes **GridValue**(numerical value), **RecordingDate**(NSdate)).  The user in one tableview can enter these two values each day and they are recorded with a fetch controller. For more understanding here is a screenshot of the **two views** concerned with the issue:

[image]

Th **Addviewcontroller** is where the user adds a new value and when user clicks on any of the two fields in the static tableview, he is redirected to the **"Zahl Datum"** view for editing.

What I would like to do is to check the **GridValue** entered by the user and display a warning(could be an alert message or in this case the footer message that would show or pop up whenever the new entered value is less than a previous value entered in a different day(a previous stored value of RecordingDate(the NSdate input attribute from CoreData model).

**Example to illustrate** if the current user enters:  Zahlerstand = **1254** and Datum: **12,05,2013**, and in a previous record the values were: Zahlerstand = **1300** and Datum: **11.05.2013.** then we see than **new value is smaller than old value** on successive dates. In this case a **warning** should be displayed(as in the tableview section footer. before he can click on "save" button in the **addviewcontroller**.

Please help with some sample code if possible.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: have you checked my answer ? Is it working for you ?

Comment: i didnt try it yet, i was hoping to ask the question here to avoid mixing with other answers. Can you post your answer here in details? Thank you

Comment: I have compared two dates using compare: method. You can compare old date with new date and then can check it is greater or not.

Comment: Can you please post it here as answer with steps to follow in your code?  I got lost a bit in the details. I am still new to iOS so this may seen trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSComparisonResult for comparing older date to newer date as :

```
compare: method returns an NSComparisonResult value that indicates the temporal ordering of the receiver and another given date.

- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate

switch ([olderDate compare:newDate]) {
case NSOrderedAscending:
    // olderDate is earlier in time than newDate
    break;
case NSOrderedSame:
    // Both dates are same
    break;
case NSOrderedDescending:
    // olderDate is later in time than newDate
    break;
}
```